# Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective and $A \subseteq X$ then $f(X-A) \subseteq Y-f(A)$. True or False?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective and $A \subseteq X$ then $f(X-A) \subseteq Y-f(A)$.

I am supposed to determine whether this statement is true or false.  If true I am to prove it.  If false I am to provide a counter example.

My definition of onto (surjective) is "A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be onto (or surjective) provided that for each $y \in Y$ there exists at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$

I honestly have no idea where to start.  I was hoping to come up with a simple example showing that this true (I think it is true) so that I could begin to understand what all the notation means.

Comment: Suppose that $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective and $A \subseteq X$ then $Y - f(A) \subseteq f(X-A)$ be true? Since I was clearly incorrect that this statement was true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an exemple of surjective function , you can use $x\mapsto \sin(x)$, with $X = [0,2\pi]$ and $Y = [-1,1]$

Now what if $A = [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$?

Comment: Then $f(A)= [-1,1]$ so $Y-f(A) = \emptyset $

Comment: What would the set $ f(X-A)$ be?

Comment: This set would be $$f([0,\frac{\pi}{2}[ \cup ]\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi] ) = ]-1,1[$$

Comment: Okay so coming up with another example: Let $ f$ be $5x-7$ $X=[0,5]$ and $Y=[-7,18]$ and $A=[1,3]$ $(X-A)=[0,1] \cup [3,5]$ so $f(X-A)= [-7,18]$.

Comment: No, it's $f(X-A)=[-7,-2[ \cup ]8,18]$

Comment: So this wouldn't work as a counter example because $ Y - f(A)= [-7,-2] \cup [8,18]$?

Comment: Indeed, if your function is bijective, then the property hold

Comment: What about a function that is strictly injective?

Comment: The property is also true.

Answer (score 0):

For such a function to be surjective means that $f(X) = Y$ (which is equivalent to your definition).

Then, given $A \subseteq X$, the set $f(A)$ is a subset of $Y$. Taking $Y/f(A)$ means taking (the set of) all the elements of $Y$ which have at least one inverse-image not in $A$, that is $X/A \subseteq f^{-1}(Y/f(A))$.

Comment: Probably the hypotesis on the continuity is not necessary.

Comment: This has nothing to do with topology, just set theory.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I said that the continuity is not necessary. =)

Comment: I also meant that the openness is not necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

Use x $\rightarrow$ x mod 2 where $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $Y$ = {0,1}.

Let $A$ = {0,1,2}.  Then $f$ is surjective, and $f(X-A)$ = {0,1} = $f(A)$ = $Y$.

So $Y - f(A)$ is the empty set and clearly it doesn't contain $f(X-A)$ so we have a counterexample.

Comment: How do you come up with $f(X-A)= \{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: $X-A$ is the set {3,4,5,...}.  It includes even and odd numbers, so $f(X-A)$ = {0,1}.